# Answers to exercises in Pinhiero and Bates' book

Tags: lme4-nlme, references

Can anyone tell me where to find the answers to the Exercises in Pinhiero and Bates' book *Mixed Effects Models in S and S-Plus*? I want to check my answers against someone who knows better.